# Try to calculate YearWeek - 202153 --> 202100 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, datepart

I try to calculate a yearisoweek in SQL Server.

To get that, I use the following formula:

```
Datepart(year, Date) * 100 + datepart (iso_week, Date) AS ISOYearWeek
```

The issue is that I get for 02.01.2021 --> 202153

Is there a possibility to get maybe 202100 instead of 202153, because the graph in my BI tool looks awful.

Comment: Well `00` is not a valid week number, and pretending that week 53 of 2021 comes *before* all the other weeks, rather than *after*, would lead to a graph that's misleading, which is worse than one looks awful. I assume you'd want `202200` instead, if you wanted this at all. A `CASE` could help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing is that there is a 202053 and a 202153 for the 30.12.2020 and the 02.01.2021... For the 02.01.2021 i get the year(2021) and the isoweek(53) becuase it was really week 53 also in the new year. The question is now how to show that in a graph ?

Comment: Ah I see, your problem is that you don't have the year belonging to the ISO week so the week ends up with the wrong year, right? That's a [separate calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26926271/4137916).

Comment: We have a similar issue in a system we work on. However, we use a date table which includes all days, iso weeks, month, year and son on. Additionally we have a table, where certain dates are shifted to another week. This second table is considered while populating the date table. So we can shift dates to week 00 or week 54 (we have both cases). Another approach (we followed this in another project) would be to calculate the number of days of the week at hand in the current year and either shift the whole week to the next year (week 0) or to the current year (week 54).