# Why does my query still return values for week 53 even though the year consists of 52 weeks?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My goal is to query all weeks within multiple a range of multiple years, with respect to the Gregorian calendar.

This would mean that:
2020 = 53 weeks
2021 = 52 weeks
2022 = 52 weeks
2023 = 52 weeks

[image]

Why does the following query then return a values for year 2021 - WEEK 53?

```
SELECT
    *
FROM (
    SELECT
        YEAR(DateTime) AS Year,
        'WEEK ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DateTime)), 2) AS Week,
        MAX(Value) - MIN(Value) AS Value
    FROM
        DummyData.dbo.SampleData
    WHERE
        TagName LIKE '%ENERGY_SAMPLE_1%' AND
        DATEPART(YEAR,DateTime) >= '2020' AND
        DATEPART(YEAR,DateTime) <= '2022'
    GROUP BY
        YEAR(DateTime),
        DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DateTime)

) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    SUM(Value)
    FOR Week IN (
        --[WEEK 01], [WEEK 02], [WEEK 03], [WEEK 04], [WEEK 05], [WEEK 06], [WEEK 07],
        --[WEEK 08], [WEEK 09], [WEEK 10], [WEEK 11], [WEEK 12], [WEEK 13], [WEEK 14],
        --[WEEK 15], [WEEK 16], [WEEK 17], [WEEK 18], [WEEK 19], [WEEK 20], [WEEK 21],
        --[WEEK 22], [WEEK 23], [WEEK 24], [WEEK 25], [WEEK 26], [WEEK 27], [WEEK 28],
        --[WEEK 29], [WEEK 30], [WEEK 31], [WEEK 32], [WEEK 33], [WEEK 34], [WEEK 35],
        --[WEEK 36], [WEEK 37], [WEEK 38], [WEEK 39], [WEEK 40], [WEEK 41], [WEEK 42],
        --[WEEK 43], [WEEK 44], [WEEK 45], [WEEK 46], [WEEK 47], [WEEK 48], [WEEK 49],
        [WEEK 50], [WEEK 51], [WEEK 52], 
        [WEEK 53]
    )
) AS PivotTable;
```

Resulting in :

[image: Week 53 for year 2021 should be NULL]

Why does week 53 of 2021 contain a value ?   in the first added image ISO_WEEK returns 52 weeks for the year

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `2021-01-01` to `2021-01-03` is iso week 53

Comment: Per Squirrel, that date range is ISO week 53 of *2020*. You do `GROUP BY YEAR(DateTime)` but the ISO year of the ISO week has its own relation.

Comment: If only there was an `ISO_YEAR` feature...

Comment: @Squirrel i still fail to understand what change i need to make to get so i get only values for each week with regard to the gregorian calendar. which would mean no result for week 53 2021 - i understand that the WK 53 values returned for 2021 are actually not at the end of the year - but remaining days of the last year. but how would i exclude this week in a proper way?

Comment: You need to define what your own week number means.

Comment: So for the dates `2021-01-01` to `2021-01-03`, do you want to report under year `2021` or  year `2020`?

Comment: 2021-01-01 to 2021-01-03 return a `ISO_WEEK` of 53 because they are in (ISO)week 53 of the year 2020. Depending on which definition of week you want to use (US - week 1 = Jan 1 or ISO = week 1 = first Thursday) the first and the last days of each year may belong to a week of the previous or next year. You have to decide which definition of a week you want to use and then calculate the correct year this week belongs to in your report

Comment: You can get the `ISO_YEAR` of a date as in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26926271/sql-get-iso-year-for-iso-week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to classify dates `2021-01-01` to `2021-01-03` under year 2020, you can compute your own `ISO_YEAR` and then group by that.

```
    SELECT ISO_YEAR = YEAR([Date])
                    + case  when DAY([Date]) <= 7 
                            and  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, [Date]) >= 52
                            then -1
                            else 0 
                            end
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/rZx2SYNY) demonstrated effect on groping by `ISO_YEAR` instead of `Year([Date])`

For your query, you can use a cross apply to compute it and change to use it in the GROUP BY clause

```
SELECT
    YEAR(i.ISO_YEAR) AS Year,
    'WEEK ' + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DateTime)), 2) AS Week,
    MAX(Value) - MIN(Value) AS Value
FROM
    DummyData.dbo.SampleData
CROSS APPLY
(
    -- compute ISO_YEAR
    SELECT ISO_YEAR = YEAR(d.[Date])
                    + case  when DAY(d.[Date]) <= 7 
                            and  DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, d.[Date]) >= 52
                            then -1
                            else 0 
                            end
) i
GROUP BY
    YEAR(i.ISO_YEAR),
    DATEPART(ISO_WEEK,DateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on Squirrel's comment.

**Just an illustration**

```
Select Date   = D
      ,DOW    = DateName(WeekDay,D)
      ,WeekNr = DatePart(WEEK,D)
 From  ( Select Top 366 N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) 
           From master..spt_values n1, master..spt_values n2
       ) A
 Cross Apply ( values ( convert(DATE,dateadd(DAY,N,'2021-01-01')) ) ) B(D)
```

**Results**

```
Date        DOW         WeekNr
2021-01-01  Friday      1
2021-01-02  Saturday    1
2021-01-03  Sunday      2
2021-01-04  Monday      2
2021-01-05  Tuesday     2
...
2021-12-19  Sunday      52
2021-12-20  Monday      52
2021-12-21  Tuesday     52
2021-12-22  Wednesday   52
2021-12-23  Thursday    52
2021-12-24  Friday      52
2021-12-25  Saturday    52
2021-12-26  Sunday      53
2021-12-27  Monday      53
2021-12-28  Tuesday     53
2021-12-29  Wednesday   53
2021-12-30  Thursday    53
2021-12-31  Friday      53
2022-01-01  Saturday    1
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i understand the issue now. but i fail to implement an solution on how to exclude Week 53 for 2021, how should i approach this?

Comment: @leroyv The 52 weeks is a year is a common misconception.   Sure, if you take  365 days divided by 7 you get an int of 52  ... BUT the decimal is 52.148857 .   This plus the fact that  years will begin on different days of the week.   Life is not black and white.  Embrace the grey.

Comment: But if you are talking about ISO weeks (like op seemingly is) then 2021-01-01 is not in week 1 of 2021 but in week 53 of 2020 and week 1 of 2021 starts on 2021-01-04, because as of ISO standard the first week of a year is the week that contains the first Thursday of a year (or in other words has at least 4 days belonging to that year)